# How to use multiple SQS(queue service) instance in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I wanted to push messages to multiple SQS queues parallel or one after another, but it should be dynamic and when I start the worker it should fetch the messages from both the queues and differentiate.
How can I achieve this in **Lumen**? 
**UPDATE**
How to use multiple worker for different queues with different amazon SQS instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see Lumen and Laravel use the exact same code to handle queues so here's something that might work, though I haven't tested it.

Run the queue worker as:

```
 php artisan queue:work --queue=queue1,queue2
```

This will mean that jobs in queue1 are processed before jobs in queue2 (unfortunately this is the only way to listen to multiple queues)

Then in your job:

```
class MyJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


   public function handle()
   {
       if ($this->job->getQueue() === 'queue1') {
          //Things
       } else {
          // different things
       }
   }
```

If you need to use multiple connections you can't do that using a single worker, however you can use multiple workers at a time. First configure your connections e.g. in your `config/queue.php`

```
'connections' => [
      'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => 'your-public-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret-key',
        'prefix' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id',
        'queue' => 'your-queue-name',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],
    'sqs2' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => 'your-other-public-key',
        'secret' => 'your-other-secret-key',
        'prefix' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-other-account-id',
        'queue' => 'your-other-queue-name',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],
]
```

If you're using supervisor then setup your supervisor configuration, if not you'll have to start both workers manually. Here's a supervisor configuration you can use:

```
[program:laravel-sqs-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --queue=queue1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data 
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log

[program:laravel-sqs2-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs2 --queue=queue2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

Alter the paths and user settings according to your app.

Comment: Actually I wanted to listen the different queues from different amazon accounts, how can I achieve that?

Comment: As far as I can see there's no way for a single worker to listen on multiple "connections". You should run multiple workers for that.

Comment: How to use multiple worker at same time, with different queue URL's for SQS?

Comment: Well first setup each connection in your configuration (e.g. name them sqs1, sqs2) if you're using supervisor (which I would recommend) check out [the supervisor configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration) this configuration is for a single worker but you can have multiple suck configurations in a configuration file so in practice run multiple workers

Comment: Thank you for this, I will check with it. Please update your answer. ;)

Comment: I am using lumen, It doesn't contain config files, so where should I put those multiple connection?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. You can put things like `config(['queue.connection.sqs2' => [ /* connection 2 props */ ]]);` where you would boot your application and that *should* work but beyond that I'm not entirely sure.